# Implementing level completion counter in a game

Tags: java, android, counter

I'm making an android game where each level have difficult task to do in order to complete the level. Let's say there are 50 levels.

I want to add 50 counters, one for each level. This counters should be online. When someone completes a level, counter adds +1 to final sum. And sum for each level is visible in level menu.

Example:

Level 1 - 345 solvers
level 2 - 245 solvers

...

Level 50 - 3 solvers

Is there any simple way to do this?
Using Google Play Game Services?
Using Firebase?

Comment: This is likely solved a number of times already, maybe try the question here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: I can´t quite understand the problem here. You should have those counters on your server and update accordingly every time one user reaches the threshold to increase. Isn´t this a simple update and retrieval? Send userid and completedLevel, perhaps a token to assure it comes from your app, and you are done.

Comment: My question is:
Can it be done with any existing service like Google Play Game Services or Firebase? I don't have separate server, it's my hobby project at home. So I need simple solution like google play game service to count this 50 counters. But I'm not sure that it can be done with google play game services.

What is best, simplest and cheapest (potentially free) solution to do this?